# Combining variables from different selectors

Tags: css, css-variables

Is it possible to combine a variable with another if it's from a different selector?

Some thing like this?

```
:root {
    --shadow: 1px 1px var(--color);
}
.blue {
    --color: blue;
    text-shadow: var(--shadow);
}
.red {
    --color: red;
    text-shadow: var(--shadow);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this simply by using Sass

Example:

$color: #c6538c;

$shadow: 1px 1px $color;

Check https://sass-lang.com/documentation for more.